# Factorize singly infinite singular matrix to shifting matrix

Tags: infinite-matrices

Claim:
For any singly infinite non-invertible matrix $A$, let $A$ to be injective and $A=BC$, where $B$ is invertible, and $C$ is a product of shifting matrices.

Is this claim true? Any reference would be nice.

By shifting matrices, I mean ones only on the superdiagonal or subdiagonal, and zeroes elsewhere.

Comment: When you say invertible do you mean (a) "invertible as a bounded linear operator" or (b) "invertible solely when considering it as a matrix"? As an example, the compact linear operator $K=\operatorname{diag}(\frac1n)_{n=1}^\infty$ does not have bounded inverse but when considered as an infinite matrix *formally* has inverse $\operatorname{diag}(1,2,3,\ldots)$ which is not defined everywhere anymore (i.e. there exist square-summable infinite vectors which are mapped to something non-square-summable). I am asking because choosing $A=K$ yields a counterexample *if* you go by definition (a).

Comment: @FrederikvomEnde Sorry that I did not make it clear. Let us say that it is (b).